# How to use a date in another feild of other date field is blank in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set of close to 2000 in an excel file. I have two date fields. I need to get a count on Date field one based on different date ranges however if date field one is blank, I need to use Date field two to add to the count. I'm not sure how to do that. I'm sure it can be done with an if statement of some sort but I'm currently at a loss

Here's an example of only counting the one column. How can I say "if A3 is blank, use B3"?

`=COUNTIF('TABNAME'!A1:A2000,"<="&TODAY()-365)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(((A:A<=TODAY()-365)*(A:A<>"")+(A:A="")*(B:B<>"")*(B:B<=TODAY()-365))>=1))
```

[image]

Explanation:

Part `(A:A<=TODAY()-365)*(A:A<>"")` counts non empty cells in col A where date is less than year ago.

Part `(A:A="")*(B:B<>"")*(B:B<=TODAY()-365)))` counts non empty cells in col B where cell in col A is empty and date in col B is less than year ago.

By summing both parts we get total count of dates according to your conditions (I hope).

`--` converts bool to int value so `SUMPRODUCT` can sum it, but you can ignore this part as formula works without it and `>=1`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A:A<=TODAY()-365)*(A:A<>"")+(A:A="")*(B:B<>"")*(B:B<=TODAY()-365)))
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what we're doing with this one. Can you explain it? Also, why the `--` in the beginning of the formula? What is that for?

Comment: @WeVie see edit

Comment: Thanks. Here's another kink. What if I want dates between say 364 and 300 days old?

Comment: The formula seems to take a ton of processing by the way. It's crashing Excel and I keep getting a message about "circular something or other"

Comment: @WeVie if you get circular reference error, you obviously put this formula in ```A``` or ```B``` column. Try to change full column reference to specific range - say ```A:A``` to ```A1:A2000``` and ```B:B``` to ```B1:B2000```. This also will help with calculation speed.

Comment: I did only use the range of the data and not the entire column

Comment: To count dates for period add another condition - i.e. instead ```(A:A<=TODAY()-365)``` use ```(A:A>=TODAY()-364)*(A:A<=TODAY()-300)``` and same for ```B```

Comment: @WeVie Can you publish sample file in google docs or onedrive and post link here?